# AJAX Call on ExpressionEngine Install

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax/customcss",
    data: {channel: currentChannel},
    })
    .done(function( data ) {

        var jsonObj= JSON.parse(data);

        console.log(jsonObj);


});
});
```

I get this error:

```
POST http://mywebsite.com/ajax/customcss 403 (Forbidden)
```

Which is a cross scripting error.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That is **not** a cross scripting error necessarily, but probably is in your case. I can think of a bunch of ways to send out 403's from my server. Anyways, what script does that post to? Is that an EE template group ("ajax") and template ("customcss")?

Not sure why you are going about it that way, but POSTing to templates should always bounce without a CSRF token. Add one!

```
....
data: {channel: currentChannel, csrf_token: "{csrf_token}"},
....
```

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/guidelines/security.html#id13